# Como capturar as 5 últimas caracteres de uma URI

Tags: java, android

Olá galera gostaria de saber como posso capturar as 5 últimas caracteres de um link, por exemplo neste link abaixo gostaria de capturar as caracteres ".m3u8"

*https:painel.iptvmove.com:25461/live/teste/1234/1224.m3u8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método [**substring**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

```
String.substring(tamanho da string - 5);
```

Ex:

```
String uri = "https://painel.iptvmove.com:25461/live/teste/1234/1224.m3u8";

System.out.print( uri.substring(uri.length() - 5) );
```

[**Demonstração**](https://ideone.com/h2vFGD)

Como bem lembrado pelo @Ronaldo Peres, valide sempre os valores (seja com ajuda de bibliotecas, regex etc).

```
String uri = "https://painel.iptvmove.com:25461/live/teste/1234/1224.m3u8";

/* Validação com a classe URL */
try {
    new URL(uri);

    System.out.print( uri.substring(uri.length() - 5) );
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println( "URL Inválida" );
}

/* Validação com a classe URLUtil */
if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(uri)) {
    System.out.print( uri.substring(uri.length() - 5) );
}

/* Verificação do tamanho da URL */
if (uri.length >= 5) {
    System.out.print( uri.substring(uri.length() - 5) );
}
```

Comment: Também verifique se o tamanho da string é maior do que 5

Comment: Muito Obrigado!